# replace / with "" and " " with %20 in one go on a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I insert some strings in an array but before I do that I want to do what topic says. To only replace space with %20 I do:

```
Name.push(linkText.replace(" ", "%20"));
```

But how do I perform two "replace" there in one go?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are trying to encode plaintext to use it in a URL or query string. I suspect you would be better off using one of javascript's built-in encoding methods, encodeURI or encodeURIComponent. See:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace two spaces in a row with one %20?

```
Name.push(linkText.replace(/ +/g, "%20"));
```

Or do you want to replace 2 spaces with %20%20?

```
Name.push(linkText.replace(/ /g, "%20"));
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear with my question. I want to remove any / and also replace a space with %20.
so for example one two/three will be one%20twothree

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

`Name.push(linkText.replace(" ", "%20").replace("/", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using a single function call in regular JavaScript.

You could do this:

```
Name.push(linkText.replace(" ", "%20").replace("/", ""));
```